# Need dropdown to retain focus (stay open) as results in datatable are updating (which takes focus away)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I have a jquery dropdown that closes because results in a datatable are updating. As the datatable updates/adds more results it takes the focus away from the dropdown, thereby causing the dropdown to close. I need it to stay open.

I have considered stopPropogation() but it seems like there would be a more elegant and potentially less dangerous solution

```
            <li id="links" class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="visible-xs visible-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Links <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <a href="#" class="visible-sm visible-md dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/log" target="_blank">Log</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/library" target="_blank">Library</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/documents" target="_blank">Documents</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/idl" target="_blank">IDL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/plots" target="_blank">Plots</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="/about" target="_blank">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by getting the value of the dropdown class, before updating the datatable, then resetting the value of the dropdown to that from before.

let initValue = $("#links").get(0).className;

```
table.ajax.reload(function (json) {
// do things 
// after all tasks completed

 $("#links").addClass(initValue);
});
```